# .Net MAUI iOS only supports later version (iOS 16)

Tags: ios, .net, visual-studio-mac, maui, .net-maui

I am running Visual Studio for Mac Preview v17.4 with MAUI workload, but when I try to run the hello world app on my iOS 15 device I get an error to downgrade to a lower version but I can't do so in the project build settings because the only available version is 16.
[image]

Any ideas how to add iOS 15 build targets to VS for Mac MAUI?

Comment: Do you have the iOS 15 sdks installed?

Comment: I suspect VS doesn't fully implement Xcode's current way of managing SDKs. To rule out it being a Maui issue, or a "Preview" issue, in VS 2022 (NOT Preview) I created a Xamarin.Forms project. Did on both Mac and VS. I'm running Xcode 13.4.1 which is SDK 15.5 - and those are the only devices shown.  Yet Xcode / Window / Devices and Simulators / Simulator tab shows (and can run) old 12.4 simulators (e.g. iPhone 6, which is too old to update beyond 12.4). Testing now to see if Xcode / Preferences / Components / Simulators tab, download a different Simulator, makes it show up for VS.

Comment: @Jason Yes, I'm able to target iOS 15 just fine in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug right now where the simulator dropdown is reading from the Info.plist file. Add an entry into your Info.plist file for the following property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/minimumosversion that matches the Minimum OS Version you've selected for your iOS target. You might have to restart vsmac or unload/reload your project. After doing this your lower version simulators should show up.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you have Xcode 14 . So download Xcode 13.4.1 version and select this Xcode in the path to see the simulators coming back. For now .netmaui is not completely supporting xcode 14. They are working to target Xcode 14. For now jus downgrade Xcode version below 14.